# jtsage datebox changes my header from fixed to inline

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobiscroll, datebox

I have a strange problem when I try to use jtsage databox.
The header and footer of my jquerymobile page are supposed to be "fixed".
And until the user opens the data picker, these header and footer do stay fixed.
But after the datepicker is used, the header and footer are no longer "fixed".
Why not? (And what other strange things does datepicker do when the user touches it?)
Example [here](http://www.activemetrics.ch/test/f1.html)

Comment: humm,... if the user touches datepicker a second time, then the header goes back to "fixed". thats pretty strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully replicated your problem and found s solution.

Your problem comes from picture placed in your header left side. For some reason datebox will cause header and footer to change its height when a date is selected. If you remove the logo  this problem will disappear. But of course you can't remove a company logo.

So to fix your problem you should remove **`data-position="fixed"`** from your header but leave it in your footer. You only really need it in the footer. This will solve your problem.

**EDIT :**

My advice is go with this date picker: http://mobiscroll.com/

It can be customized much much better then Datebox not to mention it has a different mobile platform skins so it can look like native Android or iOS datepicker. Not to mention there are skins for older and newer Android and iOS versions.

#### More info:

If you want to find more about jQuery Mobile date pickers take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/10-life-saving-jquery-mobile-plugins/)**.

Comment: i tried your suggestion here...  http://www.activemetrics.ch/test/f2.html  but i dont think it helped. the footer still disappears after using datebox. please notice that the problem gets solved by using datebox a second time. if i could simulate a second use, it might solve the problem. but how would i do that?

Comment: Tell me what browser are you using ti test this? Also have you thought of using other date pickers? There are 2 more built specially for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: right now i can only test on firefox and chrome running on windows. i did see the general problem earlier today on an iphone but i dont have access to one at this moment.

Comment: I ask because when I test it on Win7 Firefox it works fine, when I test it on Chrome it resizes and hides but not fully (I fixed it as I described it for you). My advice is go with this jQM date picker: http://mobiscroll.com/

Comment: thanks for both of your suggestions. i am sure one or the other way will work out in the end.